Azure AD B2C Claim type provokes 400 error on token
I am currently working with a custom policy which is a sign up/sign in flow.
This is my ClaimType in BaseFramework.xml

This is my Relying Party on my sign_up_sign_in.xml custom policy.
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="department" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_60ff67a2f09a4e249ae25c78e949d06d_Gender" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="false" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="eventCase" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:eventCase}"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>

I am currently trying to retrieve a query parameter from the url, called "eventCase".
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="eventCase" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:eventCase}"/>
In the azure portal, this implementation works perfectly.
But on my application after being redirected from the login I get the following:

and in network tab
400 request error with following message:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADB2C90085: The service has encountered an internal error. Please reauthenticate and try again.\r\nCorrelation ID: 3ec11ccf-f156-45d3-a09e-05314e938c6b\r\nTimestamp: 2024-12-10 16:16:02Z\r\n"
}
Note that the only change is the eventCase Output claim added in the custom policy, without it, everything seems to work correctly.
References:
Passing a paramer via url:
Azure B2C - Pass Parameter via URL to ClaimType to Claim in Token
Official Sample project that I am using:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples
Basically I expected the behavior on Azure portal to be the same as the application:
Add a custom parameter that could be empty or w/e, but if needed, it would have information.
Once again, this works correctly through the azure ad b2c by adding the parameter in end like "&eventCase=randomstuff".

It seems the eventCase query parameter isn't being passed correctly or handled in the custom policy. Ensure that the query parameter is included in the request URL properly and that the custom policy is configured to extract and use it, otherwise, the token request fails due to an invalid grant.
